# how to upload big files to GEE as assets with the API?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I try to upload big files to Google Earth Engine (10 000 points on the surface of a medium country) as assets. If I go through the code editor and Assets -> New -> .csv file It work like a charm.

I am using the Python API and I would like to do the same without going to the code editor.
What I did is the following :

```py
import ee
import geemap
import pandas as pd 
import geopandas as gpd
  
# create a tmp gdf
df = pd.read_csv(load_df['pathname'], sep=None, engine='python')
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, 
    crs='EPSG:4326', 
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(
        df[load_df['lng_column']], 
        df[load_df['lat_column']]
    )
)
    
# convert it into geo-json 
json_df = json.loads(gdf.to_json())
    
# create a gee object with geemap
ee_object = geemap.geojson_to_ee(json_df)
    
# upload this object to earthengine
asset = os.path.join(folder, asset_name)
            
#create and launch the task
task_config = {
    'collection': ee_object, 
    'description':asset_name,
    'assetId': asset
}
task = ee.batch.Export.table.toAsset(**task_config)
task.start()
```

Problem being the created asset is too big to be exported. Is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided creates an in-memory asset that you then try to export to a permanent asset. Looks like the in-memory asset is too big (this should work if you use a small data file).

You have as usual two solutions:

#### CLI

Instead, use the [earthengine upload table command](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line#upload):

```
earthengine upload table --asset_id=users/username/myUploadedShapefile gs://bucket/foo.shp
earthengine upload table --asset_id=users/username/myUploadedCSV gs://bucket/foo.csv
```

#### Python API

based on the same code but in the [api](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/e2a11a25593a839c2c56719763c73a5297fec53d/python/ee/data.py#L1392)

```py
ee.data.startTableIngestion(request_id, params, allow_overwrite=False)
```