# Upload large shapefiles stored locally to GEE assets through CLI

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

Trying to a upload large shapefile (400k point geometries covering the whole world) as an asset to Google Earth Engine using the CLI instead of the online Code Editor > Assets > New.

The following command ([from this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382593/how-to-upload-big-files-to-gee-as-assets-with-the-api)) only works *for a shapefile stored in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket*:

`earthengine upload table --asset_id=users/username/myUploadedShapefile gs://bucket/foo.shp`

Is there an alternative *for a shapefile stored locally?*

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct alternative for uploading a table from a locally stored shapefile (other than using the code editor to upload it, but I assume you already tried this and it failed due to the large file size).

One workaround using python could be to:

1. read your shapefile (e.g., using geopandas)
2. split it into multiple tiny pieces, such that the geojson representation of each piece fits within EE's [request payload size](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/usage#request_payload_size),
3. create a ee.batch.Export.table.toAsset task for each piece of the collection at a time, to a folder within your project or personal assets.

Finally, in a second script (could be python or javascript),

4. merge all the pieces into a single ee.FeatureCollection (make sure you [flatten](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-flatten) it), and finally export it as a single asset.

This could involve some trial and error, so I would recommend trying this with a smaller shapefile first.